# Scroll just a section in CollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, scroll, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying out `collectionView` and it's alright to configure it by loading data, working with customCells just like `UITableView` which is a part that I have dealt too much I know pretty much about their functionality.

One thing though that I am finding new on `UICollectionView`s is the `flowLayout` function. I am being able by using this function to give the collectionView the scrolling with multiple items on `CollectionView` on the method below

```
-(void)setupCollectionView
{
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    [flowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];
    [flowLayout setMinimumInteritemSpacing:2.0f];
    [flowLayout setMinimumLineSpacing:2.0f];
    [self.collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:flowLayout];
}
```

But this scroll, make the whole collectionView scrollable, and I don't want to this. My Issue is to make just one section of collectionView scrollable. This function is implemented on Scribd, by scrolling just the one row (section) and leaving the others at peace. This is how it looks on Scribd:

[image]

What I want to know is there any way to achieve this via CollectionView with the FlowLayout Function? If not can anyone refer or give me some advices related to this issue?

Thanks,

3r1d

Comment: Are you sure this is not 3 collectionViews with 1 section and not 1 collectionView with 3 sections ?

Comment: In fact To make this, I would use a tableView with collectionViews embedded in custom tableViewCells

Comment: @3r1d For that you need to add `UICollectionView` in `UITableViewCell` and other Option is to add 3 or more `UICollectionView` in `UIScrollView`. and 3rd option is to add `UICollectionView` within `UICollectionViewCell`

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you want to scroll to the next section, just call this method

```
-(void)scrollToNextSection{

    //Get all the visible cells
    //Get the index path of the first cell
    NSIndexPath *currentFirstVisibleItem = [[yourCollectionView indexPathsForVisibleItems] firstObject];

    //Scroll to the next section based on the visible cell current section
    [yourCollectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:currentFirstVisibleItem.section+1]
               atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionTop
                       animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: From what I see here, you are misunderstanding me. I don't want to scroll to a specific section, I want to scroll a specific section with items on it. Just like Scribd does!